# Is it possible to directly set the registers that control the ADC clock on the Arduino?

Tags: arduino-yun, adc

Is it possible to directly set the registers that control the ADC in an Arduino Yun (micro-controller side is essentially a Arduino Leonardo) from a sketch or is there a specific file somewhere you must edit?

I am working on a project that collects a signal digitizes it and sends it through a digital filter. I looked up the Datasheet for the micro-controller on the Yun and wrote the code setting the registers associated with the ADC portion of the micro controller. The code setting the registers was something like `REGNAME = 0x01;`. Yet when tested several of the associated registers were unaffected. Pointers on the process to set the ADC manually without using the `analogRead()` function would be appreciated.

Edit:
My original code looked something like this:

```c++
void setup(){
    // register to turn on ADC
    REG1 = REG1 | 0x01;

    //register to set sample rate and set ADC to Free Running Mode
    REG2 = REG2 & 0x30;

    // register to set other settings
    REG3 = REG3 | 0xF1;
}

void loop(){
    // code to take samples from ADC
    // and send them through a digital filter here.
}
```

Comment: Which part of the datasheet are you having trouble with?

Comment: The problem wasnt the datasheet. when I set the registers in the code they were not set on the microcontroller when I tested it.

Comment: the sketch recognized the register names and out of the 3 or 4 registers I set only one actually was altered. I debugged it by printing the values of the registers after being set to the console. The output of the ADC was not the same as the input signal either.

Comment: The Arduino libraries do things to the hardware. The key is to avoid using them.

Comment: I realized that after the fact. We needed a micro-controller and Ethernet in our project but because of time constraints, the research time requirement and budget constraints we could not use a pic micro-controller which would have been the ideal choice. do you know where the libraries do things to the ADC hardware? info on the process to replace  the actual library file would be helpful too.

Comment: Do you call `analogRead` after setting the registers? `analogRead` does [change  the ADCSRB register](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/a6e36fac9da3f7d78a99fc5093e94875efac8762/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L60). So if you are setting ADC High Speed Mode (`ADHSM`), that will be overwritten. The clock prescaler is only set in the [init function](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/a6e36fac9da3f7d78a99fc5093e94875efac8762/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L356-L358), so you should be able to overwrite this **in the setup function**

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve that the Arduino library does not allow you to do?

Comment: I had intended to avoid the `analogRead()` method entirely. Because I was using Arduino as a prototyping platform to design the code only and later on I will refactor the code to work with hardware that will be mass producible. Therefore I had intended to directly control the registers so that when I port over the code to the final choice of micro-controller there will not be a relatively small amount of changes to make.

Comment: I had originally set the registers in the setup function and not in the running loop function.

Comment: There are several issues here. The first is understanding the difference between || and |, && and & in C/C++. Your should then take a look at the code for analogRead() to understand how the ADC is initialed. https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L38. This type of modification requires a lot of detailed insight into the underlaying implementation. You may need to implement your own version of analogRead().

Comment: I think I used bitwise operators in my code and made a mistake typing extra '&'s and '|'s in my example. I just edited the example to reflect that. Ill have to double check that. I am going to check the link you listed. It looks like I will have to overload the analog read function so that it works like I want it to. after that, I'll have to  figure out how to replace that part of the library and ill be good to go. @MikaelPatel if you can post an answer with the info you just commented and a link to a tutorial on how to compile a sketch with an edited library I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ill follow up after with a comment listing everything I found out.  Unless it would be better to post the follow up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your project is about acquiring signals I guess that the sample frequency is important for you. In fact you need to know exactly how much time passes from one sample to another. This cannot be achieved by simple reading the ADC in your loop(). The easiest implementation is to use an interrupt that occurs every n seconds (e.g. every overflow of timerX).

I'm going to write a pseudo-code for this:

```
void SetTimer()
{  TISREG |= 1<<Prescaler_bit   //set the prescaler
   TICNT = 0   //sdt the tarting value
   TIINT |= 1<<OVF_Interrupt_enable
   sei() //enable global interrupt
}

ISR(TIM1_OVF_vect)   //happens every [prescaler*2^bit_timer/F_CPU] seconds
{
   while( !(ADCSREG &= (1<<bit_is_ready)) ) ; //usually there is a bit that is 1 while the ADC has read the data, and 0 while it is doing the conversions

//imagine the ADC stores the 3 MSBits in the ADCHI
//and the LSBits in the  ADCLO

value_high = (ADCHI & 0b00000111);  
value_low = ADCLO;

value = (value_high << 7) | value_low;

}
```

Comment: At high sampling rates, the best option is to set the ADC in the so called "free running mode". If you read the question carefully, you will notice that's exactly what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no problem with your pseudo-code. You should probably post a
complete testable code in order to get better feedback.

That being said, here are a few suggestions:

1. You should *completely set* the ADC registers to the values that suit
   your application, instead of just changing a few bits here and there.
   This is because you should not care about how the Arduino core
   library initializes those registers, especially if this is a
   prototype for a final product that will not use Arduino core. For
   example, instead of

```c++
REG1 = REG1 | 0x01;
```

you can write something like this:

```c++
REG1 = _BV(FOO)   // use foo mode...
     | _BV(BAR);  // ...in the bar setting
```

where `_BV(x)` is a macro from avr-libc that expands to `(1<<(x))`,
   and the bit names are those of the datasheet, for better readability.

2. You may want to run the digital filter in the ADC interrupt service
   routine. If you can split your processing into a fast filter
   (processing every sample) and a slow filter (running on decimated
   samples), then do only the fast one in the ISR and leave the slow one
   to the main loop. I say this from experience: when I tried to do
   all the processing in `loop()` I always lost samples, which did not
   happen when I moved the filter to the ISR.
3. But then, make sure your filter is optimized to be *fast*. Avoid
   floating point operations in the ISR if at all possible.

I have written a program that looks very similar to what you are trying
to do: it samples an analog input at 9.6 kS/s and runs an
[homodyne detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homodyne_detection)
filter in order to extract the signal power in a very narrow band around
1 kHz. The ADC is set to free running mode. In the ADC ISR, I
retrieve the sample, run it through the filter, and store the result
into volatile variables. In `loop()`, I read these back from time to
time. Here is how I set the ADC:

```c++
static void configure_adc()
{
    ADMUX  = _BV(REFS0)  // ref = AVCC
           | _BV(ADLAR)  // left adjust result
           | analog_in;  // input channel
    ADCSRB = 0;          // free running mode
    ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)   // enable
           | _BV(ADSC)   // start conversion
           | _BV(ADATE)  // auto trigger enable
           | _BV(ADIF)   // clear interrupt flag
           | _BV(ADIE)   // interrupt enable
           | 7;          // prescaler = 128
}
```

The complete program is available here:
[homodyne.ino](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/0b03735d70366bc05fc6).
It was initially intended for an Arduino Uno, but it runs unmodified on
a Leonardo clone.